# Converting ZIP codes to latitude and longitude using R

Tags: r, latitude-longitude, geocoding, spatial-statistics, zip-codes

I have a data set that includes a list of zip codes. Is there a way in R to convert these zip codes to latitude and longitude coordinates?

Comment: Latlong.net is a nice place for getting individual coordinates for a single zip code...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's no strict algorithmic relationship between latitude and longitude and zip code - they're all custom areas generated by the postal service.  You need access to a dataset that codes polygons / polygon centroids by zip code.

1) Complex

Traditionally, this task (coupled with address lookup) is termed 'Geocoding'.  The most convenient method for *full* address lookup is to find a preexisting online geocoder, whether by Google Maps, Bing Maps, or ESRI.

2) Simpler

For just US zip codes, though, there is data available from the Census:

http://www.census.gov/geo/www/cob/z52000.html

I'm not familiar with R geospatial capability, but all you should need is polygon->centroid, and centroid->coordinates.

3) Simplest

This task is common enough that a preexisting centroid dataset exists:
http://coolthingoftheday.blogspot.com/2008/04/free-us-zip-code-database-as-csv.html

Comment: Census Bureau  link is broken. It probably referred to ZCTAs which are a census bureau invention. Originally based on zipcodes (which are NOT polygons and regularly change) these are polygons that are intended to be fairly constant. Ie. making them more usable for demographic purposes.

Answer (score 11):

have you looked at the [`zipcode` package](http://www.r-bloggers.com/my-first-r-package-zipcode/)?  it's basically a dataframe with ~45,000 zipcodes along with their city, state, latitude and longitude.

Answer (score 5):

I use the `geocode` function in the `ggmap` package.

Comment: will this allow zip+4 or does it only use zip centroids?

Comment: It's using Google Maps, so works however Google would. (Only get a limited number of geocodes per day.)

Comment: ...and apparently you aren't allowed to store the data (you'd basically have to query the API about every time you need it)

Comment: Do they mean you can't store them for future geocoding (i.e. creating your own cache of mappings), or that you can't store the results at all? I've used it to locate crimes in my neighborhood and certainly store the Lat/Lon of each crime for future reference. I haven't created a cache that I use to avoid Google for future geocoding, though.

Comment: Good question; I think it's OK if it's only temporarily stored by your application, but I'm not sure that "creating an independent database of places" is in compliance... of course, the letter of the law vs. the spirit of the law is always debated. See section 10.1.3 of [Google Maps TOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms). I know of many people who do things similar to what you describe, then again I've known people who've been bitten by the restrictions, too.

Comment: My reading of the TOS (thanks for the link!) is that they have to do with the presenting of maps to other people. That is, you can't make your own map service that uses Google as a back end and doesn't credit them. It doesn't appear to have anything directly to do with geocoding data. Though who knows in this litigious era...

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with few countries, there are some hints [here](https://www.geopostcodes.com/blog/zip-code-to-coordinates-converter/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/262005)

Answer (score -2):

Seems like you are using Ruby on Rails 
Try this tutorial from Ryan Bates 
http://railscasts.com/episodes/273-geocoder?view=asciicast
I've tried it before and it works perfectly. When you type address or zipcode , it will show the longitude and latitude.

Comment: He is asking for a solution in [R](http://www.r-project.org/), not Ruby on Rails.